# Username data not sent - Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a new problem when I want to update the password from the database based on the username.
I have a **forget-password.html** form like this:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('reset_password') }}" method="POST" class="needs-validation">
.....
</form>
```

for python code itself like this:

```
# FORGET PASSWORD
@app.route('/forget-password/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def forget_password():
  if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form:
    username = request.form['username']    
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = %s', (username,))
    account = cursor.fetchone()
    if account:
        return redirect(url_for('reset_password'), username=username)
    else:
      flash('Username not registered!', 'danger')
  elif request.method == 'POST':
      flash('Please fill all form!', 'danger')
  return render_template('form/forget-password.html')
```

I want to send the username data to be processed in this **reset-password.html** form

```
<form action="{{ url_for('reset_password') }}" method="POST" class="needs-validation">
....
</form>
```

I have tried the following python code, but the password in the database is not updated.

```
# RESET PASSWORD
@app.route('/reset-password/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def reset_password():

  # GET DATA USERNAME
  username = request.args.get['username']

  if request.method == 'POST' and 'password1' in request.form and 'password2' in request.form:
    
    password1 = request.form['password1']
    password2 = request.form['password2']    

    if password1 == password2:
      # HASH Password
      hashPass = sha256_crypt.encrypt(password1)

      # UPDATE PASSWORD
      cursor.execute('UPDATE accounts SET password=%s WHERE username=%s', (hashPass, username))
      mysql.connection.commit()

      # REDIRECT TO LOGIN PAGE
      flash("Password berhasil diubah!", "success")
      return redirect(url_for('login'))
    else:
    # IF PASSWORD NOT MATCH
      flash('Password not match!', 'danger')
  # elif request.method == 'POST':
  #   # IF NOT REGISTERD
  #     flash('Please fill all form!', 'danger')
  return render_template('form/reset-password.html')
```

did i miss something? or the code when I send the username data is not correct
I just want to change the password based on the username entered in the first form

Answer (score 0):

You have not shared the html for the password and username fields. Do they looks like

```
 <form action="/test_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"> 
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
   </form>
```

You could try request.values which combines the form and url values. Refer documentation of flask from [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.Request.values)